# array_combine is not working if number of parameter is not same

Tags: php

I am reading data from csv file and combining the array.i have below header in csv

First Name,Last Name,Email,Contact No

And i am giving below data in csv in respect of column

Usertest,name,test@test.com,645383638

then using array_combine() to combine the data.in this case its working fine and giving me below result

```html
Array
(
    [First Name] => test
    [Last Name] => name
    [Email] => test@tedtmsil.com
    [Contact No] => 74647454
)
```

But if i am leaving contact number blank in csv then array_combine() is not working giving me empty array()

```html
Array
(
 
)
```

```html
$dataKeys   =   First Name,Last Name,Email,Contact No;
$dataValues =  Usertest,name,test@test.com
$dataArr = array_combine(str_getcsv($dataKeys), str_getcsv($dataValues));
```

Because the number of parameter is not same in csv header and data field in row.so am not getting how to fix this.

Comment: `Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Comment: The behaviour of [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) when the number of provided keys does not match the number of values is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php#refsect1-function.array-combine-errors): *" Throws `E_WARNING` if the number of elements in `keys` and `values` does not match."*

Comment: You can use [`array_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) to fill the values array with `''` (or `null`) to the required length.

Comment: Yes i am geeting this error..Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements..but contact number may be blank in csv,in this case how to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you are putting data to csv using `array_combine`, you can make sure length of both arrays must be the same by the following code.

You can do something like this,

```
$arr1 = array("First Name", "Last Name", "Email","Contact No");
$arr2 = ["Usertest","name","test@test.com"];
$temp = array_pad($arr2, count($arr1),'');
$res = array_combine($arr1,$temp);
print_r($res);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [First Name] => Usertest
    [Last Name] => name
    [Email] => test@test.com
    [Contact No] => 
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07fd9c8883190c36fb4a62f77dbe4b7926cd0994).